# How do you make Google People API calls with Moo::Google Perl module?

Tags: perl, google-people-api

I'm trying to use the [`Moo::Google`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo::Google) module to make API calls to Google's People API. I have been able to successfully make a simple Calendar API calls but not the People API. I have the following code trying to use the People API:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use Moo::Google;

my $gapi = Moo::Google->new(debug => 0);
my $user = 'me@gmail.com';

$gapi->auth_storage->setup({ type => 'jsonfile', path => 'config.json'
+ });
$gapi->user($user);
$gapi->do_autorefresh;

$gapi->People->People->get({'resourceName'  => 'people/me', 'personFields' => 'emailAddresses'})->json;
```

However, this returns `undefined`. I've tried may different variations but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with a lower level method, `api_query()`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use Moo::Google;
use Data::Dumper qw (Dumper);

my $gapi = Moo::Google->new(debug => 0);
my $user = 'me@gmail.com';

$gapi->auth_storage->setup({ type => 'jsonfile', path => 'config.json' });
$gapi->user($user);
$gapi->do_autorefresh;

$res = $gapi->api_query( {
    httpMethod => 'get',
    path => 'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me',
    options => { personFields => 'emailAddresses' }
});

print Dumper $res;
```

If there is a better way, I'd be interested in hearing.